# How to 'force' Magento to load a different layout

Tags: layout, magento

Background: I need to be able to load upsell / crosssell products in a lightbox complete with add-to-cart functionality.

My idea for achieving this was to 'force' Magento to load products in a different layout.  I thought of using an observer on the `controller_action_layout_generate_xml_before` event (code below).

Unfortunately what I have is not working.  Any pointers (or completely different / better ideas) are much appreciated.

```
<?php 
class My_ForceLayout_Model_Observer
{
    public function changeLayoutEvent($observer)
    {
        $action = $observer->getEvent()->getAction();
        $layout = $observer->getEvent()->getLayout();

        if($action->getRequest()->getControllerName() == 'product'
            && $action->getRequest()->getActionName() == 'view') 
        {

            $update = $layout->getUpdate();
            $update->load('popup'); // for testing only
            $layout->generateXml();
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: any error messages?  can you post your layout xml to validate the `popup` handle? Do you know that your Observer is definitely getting called?

Comment: @Jonathan Day:  Thank you for the ever so obvious question _"do you know that your Observer is definitely getting called?"_.  Once I logged the observer being called, I realized I had a typo in my `config.xml` closing tag.  Duh.  This now works.

Comment: you're welcome :) I find Alan Storm's CommerceBug invaluable for debugging that sort of thing - it very quickly tells you if your xml is getting loaded by Magento, amongst a million other things!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I managed to get this to work exactly as I first intended.  Thanks to @Jonathan Day for making me realize the reason it was not working was trivial.

Config.xml:

```
<config>
    ....
<frontend>
    <events>
        <controller_action_layout_generate_blocks_before>
            <observers>
                <forcelayout>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>forcelayout/observer</class>
                    <method>changeLayoutEvent</method>
                </forcelayout>
            </observers>
        </controller_action_layout_generate_blocks_before>
    </events>
</frontend>
    ....
</config>
```

Observer.php:

```
class Unleaded_ForceLayout_Model_Observer
{
    public function changeLayoutEvent($observer)
    {
        $action = $observer->getEvent()->getAction();
        $layout = $observer->getEvent()->getLayout();

        if($action->getRequest()->getControllerName() == 'product'
          && $action->getRequest()->getActionName() == 'view')
        {
            $template = $action->getRequest()->template;
            if (isset($template) && $template != '')
            {
                $update = $layout->getUpdate();
                $update->load($template);
                $layout->generateXml();
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Local.xml:

```
<popup translate="label">
    <label>Catalog Product View Lightbox</label>
    <remove name="right"/>
    <remove name="left"/>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>page/popup.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <remove name="product.info.upsell"/>
    </reference>
</popup>
```

Product url in .phtml file:

```
echo $this->getProductUrl($_item) . '?template=popup';
```

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for. Didn't work straight away, changed the config.xml to `
<frontend>
    <events>
        <controller_action_layout_generate_blocks_before>
            <observers>
                <unleaded_forcelayout_model_observer>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>Unleaded_ForceLayout_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>changeLayoutEvent</method>
                </unleaded_forcelayout_model_observer>
            </observers>
        </controller_action_layout_generate_blocks_before>
    </events>
</frontend>`

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you want to use just regular layout udates?

```
<catalog_product_view translate="label">
    <label>Catalog Product View (Any)</label>
    <!-- Mage_Catalog -->
    <remove name="right"/>
    <remove name="left"/>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="new_catalog/product_view" 
            name="new.product.info" 
            template="new/catalog/product/view_popup.phtml">
            ...
        </block>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

If you want to change the design of your product page depends on some conditions, you could use layout handler functionality. It means that you have to check your parameters in controller and add handler for layout updates, then you could use it in layout file as any other handler. For example:

```
if ($this->check_parameters()) {
    $update->addHandle('new_magic_handler');
    $this->loadLayoutUpdates();
}
```

And in layout:

```
<new_magic_handler translate="label">
    <label>New Magic</label>
    ...
</new_magic_handler>
```

Check for details `Mage_Catalog_ProductController::_initProductLayout()`

Comment: I need to change the layout _sometimes_ (only if the product view is initiated by clicking on an upsell or crosssell product, not if initiated from a category (or search) view), not all the time.  That's why I had the idea of using an observer that can do this (based on a passed parameter).

Comment: Thank you for updating your answer. I believe your method would require an override of the controller? As per my comment to Jonathan Day above, I found a typo in a closing tag in my `config.xml` that fixed the problem.